# Customizing seekbar to generate different shades of color from color picker

Tags: android, android-custom-view, customdialog, android-seekbar

I have a requirement to create the design as similar to the image shown below (i.e Circle color picker and Custom seek bar to choose light and dark shades of the particular color chosen). For that purpose I have customized Circle color picker from the [library](https://github.com/chiralcode/Android-Color-Picker) and that too works fine. But I have no idea how to customize the Seekbar for light and dark shades of a color chosen from the picker. Kindly help me with this. Any piece of code would be helpful for me. Please let me know if my question is not clear. Thanks in advance.

[image: Design with color picker and seekbar]

Comment: have you found solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

The library link which you mentioned is broken. I suggest you to use this [library](https://github.com/LarsWerkman/HoloColorPicker) which gives you the options that you had asked. You can add this to your project by using

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
}`